# Is $ defined in the browser or JavaScript natively?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I've noticed, recently, that $ is a defined function on websites that are not using any JavaScript frameworks.

In Firefox's firebug and Chrome's developer tools, $ is defined as a shorthand function for document.getElementsByTagName(STRING)[0], document.getElementById(STRING_BEGINNING_WITH_#), document.getElementsByClassName(STRING_BEGINNING_WITH_PERIOD)[0].

Is $ now defined in some modern browsers, is this an addition to ECMAScript, or is it just these particular developer tools defining $?

Comment: Could you include some examples of where you've seen this?

Comment: I could've sworn ASP.NET websites automatically added a function `$` as an alias to `document.getElementById`, or as a special function for getting its dynamic elements on the client side...different from jQuery. Maybe it was a different identifier, but I swear I remember seeing it in examples a few years ago. I wouldn't consider it a "framework" though because you don't explicitly include it, that's why I'm mentioning it. I'm trying to find a reference for this

Comment: @Ian it's not asp.net, it's native to the browser. to test it, create a blank html file and open in a modern version of chrome. go to the console, and type `$`

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt What's available in the Console may not necessarily be available on the `window`. Some consoles do add their own functions just for within the REPL. `$` in Chrome is one of those.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I understand that, I've seen that in the past. I'm referring to something I swear I encountered years ago when working with ASP.NET. `console` and `window` are 2 different things (I'm referring to `window`)

Comment: @Ian ASP.NET Ajax does define a few methods that have a `$` in their name, but they don't one named just `$`: [`$create`, `$find`, `$get`, etc.](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Global/default.aspx)

Comment: See what it is: `console.log($.toString());`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Crap, maybe I was thinking of `$get`. I don't know why, I remember only `$`, but `$get` looks more familiar...I think that's it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$ is defined in some browser's consoles (chrome, for example, iirc) as an alias to `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`. (except for that, no, it should stay undefined)

Answer (score 2):

No.

`$` is an ordinary identifier that must be defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is *typically* an alias to `jQuery` (after referencing jQuery). If you import jQuery into your page(s), it'll assign the value of the `jQuery` variable to `$` for easier use.

The version of chrome I'm on also has it defined by default as a command line API function, which is different than the typical jQuery alias.

Comment: jQuery isn't the only library. `$` is also a PrototypeJS identifier

Comment: @Ian hence the inclusion of the word `typically` :)

Comment: Oh I saw your italicized word, I just wanted to comment with another example

Comment: @ian Oh I gotcha. Thanks for the input, I don't have any experience with Prototype to that's new to me

Comment: Me either, I've just seen countless posts about conflicts with `$` and I know it's always between jQuery and Prototype :)